# ETL sync in every sixth hour

Tags: ssis, etl, business-intelligence

I need to make a ETL sync to add new data from relational database to the database DW in SSIS. It should take place in every sixth hour.

1. How do I do it?
2. What component do I need?
3. Where can I find more material about it in the Internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to build a SSIS Package using Business Intelligence Development Studio (which is installed as part of the SQL Server Development tools). You'll then need to execute that package on a server, using a scheduling mechanism of some kind (either an enterprise scheduler, cron, or a windows scheduled job).

The Microsoft website has good information about SSIS. I would also suggest reading about ETL & Data Warehousing in books by Ralph Kimball or Bill Inmon.